# How to check specific commit on specific branch in svn

Tags: svn

How can I check the 5th commit on my branch 'dev' on svn?

I did a svn to git migration for my svn repo with some branches. So the total amount of commits isn't the same on my svn as my git repo.

Now I want to compare the commits on the branches I've migrated so I can check that the 5th commit on the dev branch in my svn is the same as my 5th commit on the dev branch in git.

So what I want is something like:

```
$ svn log https://myserver/myrepo/ -branch dev -commit 20
```

I know the above does not exist but it's to make clear what I want.

Comment: Please read your question again. You don't really explain what you're trying to do, how you attempted to do it or why the results did not meet your expectations. Remember that we cannot read you mind! ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Okay I'll add some more explanation.

Comment: So you want to view the revision log of a given path by commit position rather than revision number, is it? I don't think there's a parameter for that, you'll possibly have to fetch all revisions in a range and count. If you need to automate it, you may want to use the --xml output. Sorry I can't be of more help, I normally use a GUI client for Subversion stuff and I'm not proficient with command line switches.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yep that's my goal indeed. Thanks for the info. I'm exploring the --xml tag and try to find a way